# Checking the existence of string characters in list of strings in another list?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is there a more efficient way to compare a list of strings rather than using a for loops?

I would like to check the existence of x strings in y (at any part of y strings).

```
x = ['a1' , 'a2', 'bk']
y = ['a1aa' , 'a2lop' , 'bnkl', 'a1sss', 'flask']
for i in x:
    print([i in str_y for str_y in y])
```

Results:

```
[True, False, False, True, False]
[False, True, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: What is `x1` here?

Comment: Sorry was a typo mistake. It is now corrected.

Comment: Using `x` again in your print statement can lead to some deal of confusion. I recommend you use another name, like `z` to follow the theme.

Comment: For significant performance improvements, you need to consider 3rd party libraries, e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list compressions:

```
In [4]: [[b in a for a in y] for b in x]
Out[4]:
[[True, False, False, True, False],
 [False, True, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Testing the timing:

```
 %timeit print([[b in a for a in y] for b in x])
<lots of printing>
228 µs ± 5.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
 %timeit for i in x:   print([i in x for x in y])
<lots of printing>
492 µs ± 4.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So half the time.

Comment: That won't make a difference computation efficiency -wise.

Comment: @AKX Surprisingly it does!

Comment: Only because you're doing IO in larger blocks, I think. It's an apples-and-oranges comparison, though, since the printed output is not identical to the original solution.

Comment: Replacing `print` with a dummy `pass` function, the solutions are practically just as fast. (orig: 2.6698 / comprehensions 2.6660)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` to get all the results in one list:

```
In [61]: x = ['a1' , 'a2', 'bk']
    ...: y = ['a1aa' , 'a2lop' , 'bnkl', 'a1sss', 'flask']
    ...: 

In [62]: [i in j for i, j in product(x, y)]
```

Or as a functional approach you can use `starmap` and `product` together:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
from operator import contains

list((starmap(contains, product(y, x))))
```

Also, a vectorized BUT not very optimized is as following:

```
In [139]: (np.core.defchararray.find(y[:,None], x) != -1).T
Out[139]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `list comprehension`.

```
x = ['a1' , 'a2', 'bk']
y = ['a1aa' , 'a2lop' , 'bnkl', 'a1sss', 'flask']
print([[xi in z for z in y] for xi in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so, not a straightforward way that wouldn't require lots of precomputation anyway.

If all you need is to know whether one of the `needle`s is in the `haystack`s, use `any()` – or a good old `for` loop and `break` is even faster:

```
needles = ['a1' , 'a2', 'bk']
haystacks = ['a1aa' , 'a2lop' , 'bnkl', 'a1sss', 'flask']

for haystack in haystacks:
    for needle in needles:
      if needle in haystack:
        print((needle, haystack))
        break  # Break if finding one match is enough
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is with a for loop... 
Best thing is doing this if you want to keep the code in one line:

```
print( [[xx in i for i in y] for xx in x] )
```