# How to use pandas string contains (str.contain) in a loop?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with a column A, which is a string of strings. Each item in the series (i.e. each row in the database) is just one long string, separated by commas. I would like to create a new column called B that incrementally counts everytime an object from a separate list appears in each row of column A. For instance:

my list looks like this:

```
list = ('dog', 'bird', 'cat')
```

my dataframe looks like this:

```
A                           B
dog, bird                   2
cat, bird                   2
dog, snake                  1
cat, bird, snake            2
dog, bird, cat, snake       3
dog, bird cat               3
```

i'm trying to create a nested loop that does the following: start at df.a[0] (i.e. the first value of df.A), find out if it contains the first value of the list (i.e. 'dog'). If df.A[0] contains, then add 1 to B. then, staying in the same row of df.A, move on to the second value of the list (i.e. 'bird'). If that df.A[0] also contains this value, then add another 1 to B. etc etc.

This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
for i in df['A']:
    for j in list:
        if i.str.contains(j):
            df['B'] += 1
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

How can I tell pandas to look at the entire series, while also telling it to function as a loop with the structure identified above? Or alternatively, what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: `i` will be string since you are getting it from `A`. Try `i.split(',')` to get a list out of it. Also on a side note, variable name `list` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of notes -

1. Don't iterate over a DataFrame when you can avoid it. Always look to vectorize. If you cannot, only then use a list comprehension
2. When iterating over the column, you're iterating over individual string items. Those do not have an `.str` attribute.
3. Don't use `list` and other similar names (`dict`, `tuple`) to name variables/objects, they shadow the builtin. I've renamed your variable to `substr` below.

---

A KISS solution would involve `str.findall` + `str.len`. No splitting required.

```
substr = ('dog', 'bird', 'cat')
df['B'] = df['A'].str.findall('|'.join(substr)).str.len()
```

```
df['B']

0    2
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

If you have large strings and a lot of substrings, you may want to look at using the [Aho-Corasick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/4909087) algorithm.

Comment: This worked - thanks very much. Will look into Aho-Corasick as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve what you need involved `get_dummies`

```
df.A.str.get_dummies(', ').loc[:,lst].sum(1)
Out[849]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
dtype: int64
```

Or we just do `str.split` with `isin`

```
df.A.str.split(', ',expand=True).isin(lst).sum(1)
Out[853]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hmm, what is `lst` for you? This isn't giving me the same output. Also, in the last row, bird and cat do not have a comma separating them. So will this still work?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ lst = ['dog', 'bird', 'cat']

Comment: I get `Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.`. Any idea? I think it's because there's a column called "bird cat" that gets generated which is causing problems.

Comment: For this to work, the arg should have whitespace `get_dummies(', ')` I believe. Last row most likely a typo?

Comment: @RafaelC yep, I think so , also , if the last lane is not type , it should not count in my result

Comment: If `list` might contain elements not contained in any row, then you may want to intersect `list` with `df.A.str.get_dummies(', ').columns` before using `loc`