# Pandas find super string in one Series from another Series

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, substring

This does not need to necessarily be done in pandas but it would be nice if it could be done in pandas.

Say I have a list or Series of strings:

```
['XXY8779','0060-19','McChicken','456728']
```

And I have another list or Series which contains sub-strings of the original like so:

```
['60-19','Chicken','8779','1124231','92871','johnson']
```

And this would return something like:

```
[True, True, True, False]
```

I'm looking for a match that is something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+ < matching string in other list >
```

So in other words, something that starts with 1 or more of any character but the rest matches exactly with one of the strings in my other list.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the matches always be with the end of the strings in your first list?

Comment: Related: the standard Pandas algorithm is not particularly efficient. If you need performance, consider a trie-based method, e.g. [this Aho-Corassick solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546).

Comment: @ALollz yes, always at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use `str.contains`

`'|'.join(s2)` produces a string that tells `contains` to use `regex` and use or logic.

```
s1 = pd.Series(['XXY8779', '0060-19', 'McChicken', '456728'])

s2 = ['60-19', 'Chicken', '8779', '1124231', '92871', 'johnson']

s1.str.contains('|'.join(s2))

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: `not (not (s1.str.contains('|'.join(s2))))` also works

Comment: And if you do have characters that need escaping, `'|'.join(map(re.escape, s2))`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ That's just the double negation of what they wrote?

Comment: @Graipher Noobs has a rare sense of humor that I appreciate (-:

Comment: :) hahaha indeed

Answer (score 1):

Since it's always at the end you can use .str.endswith and `any` to short-circuit the logic. `s1` and `s2` are just your lists above (but it also works if they are `pd.Series`)

```
[any(i.endswith(j) for j in s2) for i in s1]
#[True, True, True, False]
```

You can then convert it to a series with `pd.Series` or just use that list as a mask as-is.