# Dynamically building indexes to classify records in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, series

I am trying to write a simple record classifier. I want to add a column whose value classifies a record. I want to codify my classification rules in a yaml, or similar file for maintenance purposes.

I am using Pandas as that seems to be the best way to do this with csv records in python. I am open to other suggestions. I am new to pandas and my python skills are politely described as "why does this look like perl?"

I've gotten a dataframe (trans) and I want to apply my rules as follows:

`trans['class'][(trans['foo'] > 5) & (trans['bar'].str.contains(re.compile('baz|one|two', re.I))] = 'Record Type 1'`

This works interactively. I would like to be able to generate the classifying index, `"(trans['foo'] > 5) & (trans['bar'].str.contains(re.compile('baz|one|two', re.I))"` dynamically from each rule in my yaml file. I have successfully built strings such that I have things like:

`slice = "(trans['foo'] > 5) & (trans['bar'].str.contains(re.compile('baz|one|two', re.I))"
trans['class'][slice] = 'Record Type 1'`

This doesn't work. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points to note:

1. Quotation marks denote strings in Python. Don't use them to surround calculation of Boolean masks.
2. Don't use chained indexing. It's [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the docs and can lead to unexpected side-effects, or ambiguity as to whether you are modifying a view or a copy. You can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead.
3. [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) already supports regex and defaults to `regex=True`, you don't need to use the `re` module.

For readability, you can split and combine masks. Here's an example:

```
m1 = trans['foo'] > 5
m2 = trans['bar'].str.contains('baz|one|two', case=False)

trans.loc[m1 & m2, 'class'] = 'Record Type 1'
```

The usually expensive part, calculation of `m2`, can be optimized by resorting to specialist algorithms, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546) for details.

Comment: How would you handle a situation where there are unknown number of conditions until run-time?  i.e. there could be a need for m1, m1&m2 or m1&m2&m3 and so on.  Can you iterate on this like m = m & new_condition?

Comment: Sure, you can link an arbitrary number of Boolean series in this way, e.g. `m = m1 & m2 & (m3 | m4) & (m5 | m6)`, then calculate `m = m & m7`, etc..

Comment: Thank you - I clicked up and forgot the check - doh!  This looks super helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't put the condition inside the quote. So it should be

```
slice = (trans[`foo`] > 5) & (trans['bar'].str.contains(re.compile('baz|one|two', re.I)))
trans['class'][slice] = "Record Type 1"
```

Comment: If the expression came as a string `s`, you can do `slice = eval(s)`. And notes from @jpp are all great and worth to consider, especially number 2nd.

Comment: I have built my own string in code, the eval is what was missing.  I misunderstood what the slice was representing in the chained logic.  I read the chained conversation in brief in the docs and decided it didn't  apply to my situation as I wasn't concerned about overwriting the dataframe.  That said, I am planning to avoid it now that I know how.