# How to shift numeric Values or non-numeric from a Column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

while  reading through the Pandas shift method, i was just doing some test to see if a Column in Pandas dataFrame having mixed vales like number and names and i want to segregate that in order to get the number to be aligned to a separate new column while dropping /removing them From original column.

a) **Below is mine DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
        Name  OXA
0    SAN 109  Yes
1   KENI 122   No
2  REEMA 455  Yes
```

b) **I tried with shift to move number to a new DataFrame(`Nums`):**

```
>>> df['Nums'] = df['Name'].shift(-1)

>>> df
        Name  OXA       Nums
0    SAN 109  Yes   KENI 122
1   KENI 122   No  REEMA 455
2  REEMA 455  Yes        NaN
```

The above Creates the New column as `Nums` but not getting the desired result.

**c) My Desired output will be :**

```
        Name  OXA      Nums
0       SAN   Yes      109
1       KENI  No       122
2       REEMA Yes      455
```

OR  and vice versa

```
        Name  OXA     NUMS
0       109  Yes      SAN
1       122  No       KENI
2       455  Yes      REEMA
```

Comment: I see your answer and maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/2901002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for extracting column by regex - `[a-zA-Z]+` for match one or more characters, then `\s*` for zero or more whitespaces and `\d+` for one or more digits:

```
df[['Name','Nums']]  = df['Name'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+)')
print (df)
    Name  OXA Nums
0    SAN  Yes  109
1   KENI   No  122
2  REEMA  Yes  455
```

---

```
df[['NUMS','Name']]  = df['Name'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(\d+)')
print (df)
  Name  OXA   NUMS
0  109  Yes    SAN
1  122   No   KENI
2  455  Yes  REEMA
```

If there is always whitespace separator is possible use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['Name','Nums']]  = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
    Name  OXA Nums
0    SAN  Yes  109
1   KENI   No  122
2  REEMA  Yes  455
```