# Drop rows with sub-string value given

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Drop rowsfrom dataframe given the subsstring is present in particular col's  row.

df:

```
Parent  Child   score
1stqw   Whoert      0.305125
tWowe   Tasert      0.308132
Worert  Picert      0.315145
```

substrings = [Wor,Tas]

Drop rows having the substrings.

Updated df:

```
 Parent Child   score
1stqw   Whoert      0.305125
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate and then use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
L = ['Wor', 'Tas']

df = df[~(df['Parent'] + df['Child']).str.contains('|'.join(L))]

print(df)

  Parent   Child     score
0  1stqw  Whoert  0.305125
```

For efficiency / performance, see [Pandas filtering for multiple substrings in series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541444/pandas-filtering-for-multiple-substrings-in-series).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in subset of `DataFrame` and then add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one True per row:

```
cols = ['Parent', 'Child']
mask = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(substrings))).any(axis=1)
```

Or chain boolenam mask together by `|` (bitwise OR):

```
mask = (df['Parent'].str.contains('|'.join(substrings)) | 
        df['Child'].str.contains('|'.join(substrings)))

df = df[~mask]
print (df)
  Parent   Child     score
0  1stqw  Whoert  0.305125
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! and i got some repeated rows after doing this steps ,dont know why.

Comment: @vijayathithya - Maybe some duplicates in data, try `df = df.drop_duplicates()` and if necessary test som columnsonly for dupes `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Parent', 'Child'])`