# String contains between two df in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, performance, string-matching

I have two df with two string columns as below:

Df1: Original df has 2000 rows of Names

```
Id    Name
1     Paper
2     Paper
3     Scissors
4     Mat
5     Cat
6     Cat
```

2nd Df: Original df has 1000+ Item_Name

```
Item_ID   Item_Name
1         Paper Bag
2         wallpaper
3         paper
4         cat cage
```

I need strings in column `Name` that are in column **Item_Name**

1st Approach: By using `str.contains`:

I know how to match string if their was one column and a couple of strings to be matched like below:

```
df[df['Name'].str.contains("paper|cat", na=False)]
```

*But how to do when there are two columns of string (name & Item_name) to be matched*?

2nd Approach: `Fuzzywuzzy`

```
matched = []
for row in df1.index:
    name = df1.get_value(row,"Name")
    for columns in df2.index:
        item_name=df2.get_value(columns,"Item_Name")
        matched_token=fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name,item_name)
        if matched_token> 80:
            matched.append([name,item_name,matched_token])
```

The problem will be, it will be slow and my intended output what I want is litle more which I get from fuzzywuzzy. The output looks like:

```
Id Name     Item_ID
1  Paper     1,2,3
2  Paper     1,2,3
3  Scissors  NA 
4  Mat       NA 
5  Cat       4
6  Cat       4
```

**Summarize**:

1. How to do str.contains if their are two df with different column name
2. How to transform the df to get the above intended output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function:

```
def matcher(x):
    res = df2.loc[df2['Item_Name'].str.contains(x, regex=False, case=False), 'Item_ID']
    return ','.join(res.astype(str))

df1['Item_ID'] = df1['Name'].apply(matcher)

print(df1)

   Id      Name Item_ID
0   1     Paper   1,2,3
1   2     Paper   1,2,3
2   3  Scissors        
3   4       Mat        
4   5       Cat       4
5   6       Cat       4
```

There are ways you can make this more efficient:

- Only work on unique items in `df1['Name']`: `apply` is a row-wise loop.
- Use list comprehensions instead of `pd.Series.apply`. Both are Python-level loops, but list comprehensions often outperform versus Pandas `str` methods.

But the above don't improve algorithmic complexity. For orders of magnitude better improvement, you should consider a trie-based algorithm, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546) utilizing the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

Comment: your item_ID column is String

Comment: @min2bro, Yes, so is `Item_ID` in OP's desired output.

Comment: @jpp: I will try this and get back to you

Comment: When I tried for a similar cell, it is matching with different Item_ID. Since you mentioned that it works only on unique df1['Name']. Should I do `pd.Series(df1['Name'].unique()).apply(matcher)` ?

Comment: `Since you mentioned that it works only on unique`. No, that's not what my post says. It says *if you want to improve performance*, remove duplicate values first. I can't replicate your problem with `matching with different Item_ID`.

Comment: One more issue, I guess this is with how `str.contains` work, It has not matched anything where their are two words. For example when `Name` is "Paper Bag" and `Item_Name` is "Paper". I am looking for those matches also.

Comment: Since `Paper` is in `Paper Bag`, it does match. In my output, Paper does map to `1`, and `1` refers to `Paper Bag`.

Comment: What I am trying to say is,it is opposite of what is presented in the sample df above

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. You're right, `str.contains` works one way only. If you need both ways, that's another question.

Comment: Ahh!! Is their any way you can tweak you solutions or should I ask the new question?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, Unfortunately, I think it's beyond a tweak, best to ask a new question (with a complete example so people understand what you mean!).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`df.apply`** here

```
def get_vals(df):
    return ','.join(map(str, df2.loc[df2['Item_Name'].str.contains(df['Name'], case=False),]['Item_ID'].tolist()))

df1['Item_ID'] = df1.apply(get_vals, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
Id     Name  Item_ID
1     Paper   1,2,3
2     Paper   1,2,3
3  Scissors        
4       Mat        
5       Cat       4
6       Cat       4
```

Believe this will give you your desired result

Comment: Getting an error: TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", u'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'Name':['paper','paper','scissors','mat','cat','cat']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'Name':['paper bag','wallpaper','paper','cat cage']})


import numpy as np
def lookup_prod(ip):
    lst=[]
    for idx,row in df1.iterrows():
        if ip in row['Name']:
            lst.append(row['ID'])    
    if not lst:
        return np.NaN
    return lst

df['Item_ID'] = df['Name'].apply(lookup_prod)
```

**Output:**

```
 ID  Name         Item_ID
0   1   paper     [1, 2, 3]
1   2   paper     [1, 2, 3]
2   3   scissors    NaN
3   4   mat         NaN
4   5   cat         [4]
5   6   cat         [4]
```

Comment: It is giving me all rows as Nan. I your example you have taken column names of both df as same. Can you change the same, so I can understand which ID and which Name you are referring in your code