# Keywords count in df: Performance tuning

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance

I have a df with a text column. Say:

```
d = {'text': ["merry had a little lamb and a broken limb", "Little Jonathan found a chicken"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I also have a list with ~400 keywords, for example:

```
observations_words_list = ["bent","block","broken"]
```

I wish to see how many records has more than one keyword in their text, and I'm doing this like that:

```
    df = df['text'].dropna().reset_index()
    df_len = len(df['text'])
    obs = set(observations_words_list)
    df['Observations'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(set(str(x).lower().split()).intersection(obs)))
    obs_count = len(df[df['Observations'] > 0])/df_len
```

For the sample df (in reality I read csv with ~0.5m records), I expect the new column to hold 1 for the first record, 0 for the second, and overall `obs_count=0.5`

Runtime is ***far*** from ideal, and I'm looking for a faster way to process this step.

Would love your ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541444/pandas-filtering-for-multiple-substrings-in-series) ?

Comment: Solution is `Aho-Corasick algorithm` here

Comment: That isnt applicable here as it looks for words within words, and here I believe Gavriel is just looking for whole words in the string (hence use of str.split())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***290ms for 100k * df***

I understand you just want to see how many records contain **ONE OR more** keyword, and the absolute count isnt relevant. In which case there is an even better (and in my opinion more elegant) one line solution using regex which doesn't iterate over the data using apply:

```
d = {'text': ["merry had a little lamb and a broken limb", "Little Jonathan found a chicken"]*100000}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

observations_words_list = ["bent","block","broken"]
obs = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in observations_words_list)
contains_obs = df['text'].str.contains(obs, flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
obs_count = sum(contains_obs)/len(df['text'])
```

If you wish to keep the number of observations, you can use 'count' for a small time penalty (410ms):

```
df['Observations'] = df['text'].str.count(obs, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
obs_count = sum(df['Observations']>0)/len(df['text'])
```

Comment: ya, seems OP dont care about performance.

Comment: just a different search. However I appreciated your insight as I'll be using the Aho-Corasick algorithm for myself in future :) so giving you a plus one anyway. The algo unfortunately takes 5.5 seconds for 100k*df, but of course it is doing a lot more work on the strings...

Comment: Btw, need `'|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in observations_words_list)` for word boundaries

Comment: just replaced ["bent","block","broken"] with observations_words_list for gd measure... can you accept answer?

Comment: You won buddy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following one-liner:

```
print(df['text'].str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(set(observations_words_list)).sum(axis=1).mean())
```

Output:

```
0.5
```

Comment: tested `df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: OP solution `448 ms ± 132 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Your `846 ms ± 22.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Tested your improved `df['text'].str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(observations_words_list).sum(axis=1).mean()`

Comment: @jezrael How about now

Comment: `%%timeit
df['text'].str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(set(observations_words_list)).sum(axis=1).mean()

834 ms ± 7.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: faster `10ms` only :(

Comment: Wow. I'm impressed, @jezrael

Comment: @U12-Forward Thanks for your answer!!!!! Super appreciated. Actually, I was about to implement it, as it seemed more intuitive. With that, if the other solution is twice as fast, I might go with that one. Really, super thanks! 

Comment: @GavrielGoidel Your welcome, would it be worth an upvote :)

Comment: @U12-Forward, I was blinded by the speed test, but I'm concerned about time I'll spend implementing an algorithm I don't understand. I'm considering your solution which is much more straightforward. qq - I can see why to use ```mean``` if results are binary (sum on the 1s over count = mean), but when there is more than one keywords, results might be skewed, don't you think?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel No It will still work because of `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

There is possible improvement with `mean` and `.gt(0)`:

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(set(str(x).lower().split()).intersection(obs))).gt(0).mean()
```

---

```
d = {'text': ["merry had a little lamb and a broken limb", "Little Jonathan found a chicken"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: df_len = len(df['text'])
    ...: obs = set(observations_words_list)
    ...: df['Observations'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(set(str(x).lower().split()).intersection(obs)))
    ...: obs_count = len(df[df['Observations'] > 0])/df_len
    ...: 
    ...: 
448 ms ± 132 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: obs = set(observations_words_list)
    ...: df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(set(str(x).lower().split()).intersection(obs))).mean()
    ...: 
    ...: 
324 ms ± 4.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I can see why to use mean if results are binary (sum on the 1s over count = mean), but when there is more than one keywords, results might be skewed, don't you think?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel - I need test it.

Comment: @GavrielGoidel - Another solution is faster?