# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on partial match in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dataframe, list, numpy

I have a dataframe with customer info including first and last name (seperate columns). I have an array of names and I want to remove rows if there is a partial match in the names.

For example, last name is smith-west and I have smith in the names array so that row should be removed. Is this possible?

```
df = df[~df['First Name'].isin(names)]
```

is what I currently have but the isin function only does an exact match

Comment: Maybe helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541444/pandas-filtering-for-multiple-substrings-in-series

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition : you can create a filter to exclude one name at the time. As an example if you want to exclude any individual whose name contains "Smith", the filter can be `~df["Name"].str.contains("Smith")`. If you have multiple names in a list, you can then combine them using the `&` (logical and). Below is a very short code that just does that :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"First":["Bob","John","Peter"], "Name":["Smith-West","Adams","Washington"]})
name = ["Smith", "Santiago"]
filter = True
for n in name:
    filter = filter & (~df.Name.str.contains(n))
df[filter]
```

Comment: In my case the df has a first name and last name column. How would it work in that case. Would I have to repeat the code twice

Answer (score 0):

To answer the additional question about how to filter using a similar method but filtering on two columns :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"First":["Bob","John","Peter"], "Name":["Smith-West","Adams","Washington"]})
name = ["Smith", "Santiago"]
first = ["Joe", "Peter"]

filter_name = True
for n in name:
    filter_name = filter_name & (~df.Name.str.contains(n))

filter_first = True
for f in first:
    filter_first = filter_first & (~df.First.str.contains(f))

df[filter_name & filter_first]
```

In very short, we create a first filter on `name` and a second filter on `first`. We then combine then using `filter_name & filter_first`.